# Average time a substring occurs

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a programm that returns too many results, so i want to take only the useful results that are above the average. My question is in a string length **N** that is produced from alphabet of **k** letters, how many times in average all substrings length **m** occurs? For example in the string "abcbbbbcbabcabcbcab" of alphabet {a,b,c} how many times in average all the substrings of length 3 occurs, abc occurs 3 times, bbb occurs 2 times (i count it even if they overlap), and so on. Or is there a way to know it from python (where my code is) before executing the programm?

Comment: Before executing, no. Have you tried anything to determine what you want? I'm not sure what you mean by "how often they occur on average". Counting all the substrings of length 3 is easy

Comment: Do you want to count the substrings in a specific string, or do you want the theoretical average in the general case? I guess, the probability that a string with length m occurs at any given position is 1/(k^m), so if your string is N characters long, that would make (N-m+1)/(k^m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to count the substrings in a specific string, or do you want the theoretical average in the general case? The probability that a string with length `m` of an alphabet with `k` characters occurs at any given position is `1/(k^m)`, so if your string is `N` characters long, that would make an expected number of occurrences of`(N-m+1)/(k^m)` (`-m+1` because the string can not appear in the last `m-1` positions). Another way to see this is as the number of substrings of length `m` (`N-m+1`) divided by the number of different such substrings (`k^m`).

You can calculate the average counts for your example, to see whether the formula gets to about the right result. Of course, one should not expect too much, as it's a very small sample size...

```
>>> s = "abcbbbbcbabcabcbcab"
>>> N = len(s)
>>> k = 3
>>> m = 3
```

For this, the formula gives us

```
>>> (N-m+1)/(k**m)
0.6296296296296297
```

We can count the occurrences for all the three-letter strings using `itertools.product` and a `count` function (`str.count` will not count overlapping strings correctly):

```
>>> count = lambda x: sum(s[i:i+m] == x for i in range(len(s)))
>>> X = [''.join(cs) for cs in itertools.product("abc", repeat=3)]
>>> counts = [count(x) for x in X]
```

In this case, this gives you *exactly* the same result as the formula. (I'm just as surprised as you.)

```
>>> sum(counts)/len(counts)
0.6296296296296297
```

Comment: Addendum: I repeated this with random "abc"-string with 10 and 100 characters and the actual result was _always_ exactly the same as the formula.